# The supreme distribution of Brownian motion increment

Tags: probability-distributions, brownian-motion

Let $W_t$ be an one-dimensional standard Brownian motion, and $\theta_s$ is the shift such that $\theta_s( W_t)=W_{t+s}-W_s$, then are there any reference available regarding the distribution of the following random variable:
$$\sup_{s} \theta_s(W_t)=\sup_{s} (W_{t+s}-W_s).$$

Comment: Over what range does $s$ vary?

Comment: We can consider s range over a finite domain first, say, $s\in [0,T-t]$?

Comment: For $t$ fixed and large $T$, the supremum will then behave like $\sqrt{\log T}$.

Comment: I wonder what is the distribution for $\lim_{s\to \infty}\theta_s W_t$.

Comment: How about $\lim_{t\to 0}\sup_{s}\theta_s(W_t)$?